# getting 404 error while I'm testing my express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am coding a route that gets all answers that the user has responded to, I created a model for it and create a route using express, only authenticated users can reach this route, I have middleware that checks the user's token when I'm testing the route in postman I get 404 error, I am passing the token in postman, I made sure that user has at least one answer to a question but couldn't figure out what went wrong, I appreciate any help

mongoose model

```
const answeredQuestionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  questions: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Question'
    }
  ]
});

const AnsweredQuestions = mongoose.model('AnsweredQuestions', answeredQuestionsSchema);

module.exports = AnsweredQuestions;
```

and this is the route

```
const router = express.Router();
const AnsweredQuestions = require('../models/useranswers');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

// Get all answers for a user
router.get('/answers', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const answeredQuestions = await AnsweredQuestions.findOne({ user: req.user._id });
    if (!answeredQuestions) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'No answers found for this user' });
    }
    res.send(answeredQuestions.questions);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: We don't know what went wrong either, but a 404 means the request you made isn't routed to an endpoint. We have no idea what request you made, what your middleware does, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I guess I am on the correct route as I am getting the error: no answer found for this user, which I added in my route in case of an error
so I can't think  about anything else, my auth middleware is working properly as I am not getting error that user is not authenticated

Comment: So `answeredQuestions` is falsey? We can't see the data so there's no way to help further.

Comment: it might be, as I am not seeing anything in MongoDB atlas, anyway thank you so much for your help,

Comment: Try writing unit tests. Don't code directly against Atlas